# Drupal Through error with option group “ illegal value. ” with Options element module

Tags: select, drupal, drupal-7

I just install Options element with a fresh drupal installation . When i was trying to create option group it is throughing "field_name : illegal value. "

After digging what i found is when i select a option group value it is showing error. but when i select normal then it works fine.

Error is comming from list.module line no 390 of core.

my select option are

```
test|test
<test1>
test2|test2
test3|test3
```

In this test is allowed but test2 and test3 is illegal.

Any help most welcome.

EDIT :

> Array to string conversion in list_allowed_values_string (line 350 of /var/www/html/drupal/drupal-test/modules/field/modules/list/list.module).

Comment: What that <test1> represents there? As you said it expects list in "name|value" format.

Comment: it represent optgroup

Comment: that is your problem.